# How can I combine weird JAAS LoginModules?

Tags: java, jboss, jaas

I'm working on a project involving several disparate security frameworks that have grown organically over the years. There is an interest in combining the role information without doing any migration to a single LDAP or ActiveDirectory.

Ideally, we need SSO that will consolidate role information from these sources. What is the best way to do this? Do I need multiple LoginModules that use password stacking, and then at what point would I figure out that user "wwkbf" in identity store A is the same as "user8204" in identity store B? How would I resolve problems where "manager" role in identity store A is different from "manager" role in identity store B?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You have to figure out the meaning of your LDAP data and how it can be reconciled. Only you can do that. It might be advisable to introduce some aliasing or referencing into your LDAP directories so they can be mutually reconciled.

Comment: I'm talking about writing custom LoginModules because we can't modify the "several disparate security frameworks" which use their own identity stores - none of which are LDAP.

Are you saying this type of role mapping can't/shouldn't be done with JAAS LoginModules instead of touching the underlying identity stores?

Comment: I am saying what I did say, and I'm averse to questions that start 'are you saying ...'. In my extensive experience the answer is invariably 'no'. You still have to figure out the meaning of your data, wherever it is, and only you can do that. No doubt you can combine one or more `LoginModules` to join your data, but first you are going to have to figure out what that means.

Comment: Do you have any experience answering questions for general cases without considering irrelevant implementation details? I'm mainly interested in whether I should do this type of mapping in one monolithic LoginModule or if it would be better to write one LoginModule for each identity store in such a way that password stacking will work. Are there any pros/cons to consider there?

Comment: Do you have any experience asking questions that can actually be answered? Telling you to understand your own data is not an 'irrelevant implementation detail'. It is the essence of your problem. There's no good reason to boil it all down to one LoginModule, but the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

In kind of Separation of Concern write one `LoginModule` for every identity store.

If you have to separate the roles by identity store create a set of unique (e.g. different package name) `Principal`s and `Credential`s for each identity store.

Depending on your context the user mapping could be static or dynamic.

`Static` could be a mapping file or a database containing all userIds for one user. Define which userId is the 'primary' userId (userId used by SSO provided by user). Set this `LoginModule` at the top of the stack and fill the `Subject` with all `Principal`s (one for each userId).

`Dynamic` means the every identity store knows the userId of the following identity store.